# Google Maps JavaScript API: Markers click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, maps, squarespace

I'm building an interactive map for a website built with Squarespace (friend's preference) using the Google Maps Javascript API. Basically, I have the map and all markers showing up (they are loaded through an array of objects in the format of [NAME, LAT, LONG, ADDRESS, PHONE, INFO]). What I want to be able to do however, is use listeners on all the markers so that when one is clicked, the name shows up on a label within the map, and then all of the details (address, phone, info) show up below. I already had this working on the original site. It was pretty simple. But when my friend wanted to move to Squarespace, I had to learn how their code injection works. Things get injected to the header, but I think my problem would be solved if I could put the code after the body.

What's causing the problem is that the Jquery used to fill in the details both on and below the map are referencing DOM elements, which are undefined when the script is loaded. So, my thought was to wrap the function in a $(document).ready function. When I try this though, the map doesn't load at all. Any suggestions on how I should handle this? Here's the code for loading the elements from the array 'locations' and adding the listeners:

```
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
    });

    bounds.extend(marker.position);


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            console.log(locations[i][0]);
            $('#store-text').text(details[i][0]);
            $('#store-text-2').text(details[i][1]);
            $('#phone-text').text(details[i][2]);
            $('#desc-text').text(details[i][3]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

I'm getting errors that 'click' and 'text' are null, so it's clear that it's an issue of when the DOM is fully loaded vs. when the script is loaded. As a side note, clicking markers does successfully log to the console, so that's how I'm sure the rest of the function is working as planned.

Answer (score 0):

It is curious that the map and markers render at all with the code in the head section for the same reason: `google.maps.Map` needs a DOM element that doesn't exist when the script runs.  I also can't find anything in the code snippets you've provided that would prevent this from working correctly if you wrap it in a `$(document).ready` block (minus some typos in the code example).  A boiled down code sample works for me in basic testing with a shorthand version of a document ready block:

```
$(function () {
    locations = [
        ['Chicago', 41.834270, -87.670898, '1234 Chicago St.', '111-111-1111', 'Chicago Stuff'],
        ['New York', 40.436495, -74.267578, '1234 New York St.', '222-222-2222', 'NY Stuff'],
        ['Toronto', 43.647380, -79.409180, '1234 Toronto St.', '333-333-3333', 'Toronto Stuff']
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 42,
            lng: -80
        },
        zoom: 5
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                $('#store-text').text(locations[i][0]);
                $('#store-text-2').text(locations[i][3]);
                $('#phone-text').text(locations[i][4]);
                $('#desc-text').text(locations[i][5]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        }(marker, i)))
    }
});
```

And a working jsfiddle with scripts loading in the head: http://jsfiddle.net/cwrke3mL/